# TypeError : When returning nothing in the list

Tags: python

I want to calculate moving average of the values entered by the user and also the size of average to be taken which is also entered by the user. When I enter the size of the moving average, number of elements in list and enter nothing when prompted to enter the elements in the list it again asks the user to input everything that is avg_size, size and user_list. The moving average is calculated but I also get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Program:

```
def user_input():

  avg_size = int(input("\n\nEnter the size of moving average(that should be less than the sample values size) : "))
  size = int(input("\n\nEnter size for the list or no. of values you want to enter :"))
  
  user_list = [] #Declaration of list variable

  try :

    for i in range(size):
      user_list.append(int(input("\n\nEnter the elements : ")))

    return user_list , size , avg_size    

  except ValueError:
    print("\n\nCAUTION: Entered invalid value!!!!\n\n")
    pass

  main()


def validation(l,s,s1):

  if s<s1: 
    print("\n\nCAUTION: Entered average size greater than sample size!!!!!\n\n")
    main()

  elif s==0 or s1==0 or s==1: 
    print("\n\nCAUTION: Cannot calculate moving average for this!!!!!\n\n")
    main()

  else:
    print("\n\nEverything is fine!\n\n")
    pass

def mv_avg(li,size,a_s):  

  avg_li = []

  for i in range(size): 
    if i+1 < a_s:
      avg_li.append(float('NaN'))

    else:
      avg_li.append(sum(li[(i-a_s+1):i+1])/a_s)
  print(f"\n\nThe {a_s}-year moving average for the list is as follows : {avg_li}")


def main():

  value_list , size , avg_size = user_input()

  validation(value_list,size,avg_size) 

  mv_avg(value_list,size,avg_size) 

  
main()
```

Comment: If there is no `return` statement for a given branch in a function, `None` is returned implicitly.  In your case, this is happening when `user_input` gets into its `except` branch.

Comment: Don't use recursion to restart your input cycle. `user_input` should either return the values or raise an exception, and a loop in `main` should be responsible for calling `user_input` until values are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter an invalid value to `user_input` this will cause the exception to be thrown and thus your `return` is never executed. You need to either continue asking the user to add a value when it's invalid, or just `return 0` after an exception occurs.

As another note, it appear you call `main()` quite a few times within your code; such as in `validation` and `user_input`. I don't believe this is intended as it will create quite a few level of recursion, you only need the one call at the bottom.